# Making enumerate items align at left while using xepersian

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, right-to-left, bidi, xepersian

I am in a trouble to make enumerated items at the left:

```
\documentclass{article}
‎‎     
\usepackage{xepersian}‎‎‎

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amscd,amsfonts,amssymb,enumerate}‎
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Niloofar}‎
\setdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{Yas}‎

\begin{document}‎
\maketitle‎
\noindent {\textbf{\LARGE{‎‏توابع چند متغیره}‎}}\\
\vspace*{1 mm}‎‎‎

$‎\bullet‎$ دامنه تعریف تابع های زیر را توصیف کنید:‎

\begin{enumerate}[1)]

\item {‎$f(x,y)=\frac{5x+2y}{4x+3y}$‎}‎
\item {‎$f(x,y)=‎\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}‎‎‎$‎}‎
\item {‎$f(x,y)=\frac{e^{xy}}{‎\sqrt{x-2y}}$‎}‎
\item {‎$f(x,y)=\ln(x+y-4)$‎}‎
\item {‎$z=\frac{x^2-3y^2}{x^2-y^2}$‎}‎
\item {‎$z=\frac{x+y^2}{\sqrt{x}}$‎}

\end{enumerate}‎‎
‎
‎‎‎‎‎‎\end{document}‎
```

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is using the `LTRitems` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amscd,amsfonts,amssymb,enumerate}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Niloofar}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{Yas}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\noindent {\textbf{\LARGE{توابع چند متغیره}}}\\
\vspace*{1 mm}

$\bullet$ دامنه تعریف تابع های زیر را توصیف کنید:

\begin{enumerate}[(1]
\begin{LTRitems}
\item {$f(x,y)=\frac{5x+2y}{4x+3y}$}
\item {$f(x,y)=\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$}
\item {$f(x,y)=\frac{e^{xy}}{\sqrt{x-2y}}$}
\item {$f(x,y)=\ln(x+y-4)$}
\item {$z=\frac{x^2-3y^2}{x^2-y^2}$}
\item {$z=\frac{x+y^2}{\sqrt{x}}$}
\end{LTRitems}
\end{enumerate}

‎\end{document}‎
```

BTW you can ask your questions regarding the `xepersian` package on [ParsiLaTeX](http://qa.parsilatex.com) Q2A site.